# Representing genealogy when multiple intra-familial marriages occurred

Tags: relationship-analysis, software-recommendations, family-tree

I searched this site and found a similar question from 2012. I'm hoping that genealogy programs have improved since then. I have a genealogy in which multiple intrafamilial marriages occurred. Specifically, a family that was rather prolific over generations settled in an area and their descendants have remained in that area for over 300 years. Along my lineage four successive marriages occurred among relatives of varying degrees. The genealogy programs I have tried so far duplicate common ancestors to illustrate their multiple roles in the genealogy. I would prefer a representation that does not duplicate (what a mathematical/computational puzzle!).

Is there a program out there that could do this?

Given the variations of relationships, the genealogy quickly explodes with duplicates. I have a GEDCom file, so I could import into a compatible program.

I wanted an ancestor-descendant representation that would show the interconnections created by marriages within a multigenerational, large family (e.g., one man is related to both members of a particular marriage via 5 sons from 2 different mothers).

If a person is the great-grandparent of a husband and the distant uncle of the wife, in the genealogy software I have used so far, that person is shown twice in the graphical representation of the genealogy - once for each of those two roles. Apparently this is a common feature of many genealogy programs. What I want to achieve is a genealogy in which each person is shown only once, regardless of how many "roles" that person has. I have already verified that I do not have any individuals entered more than once, and I am not looking to delete any person. I am looking to avoid having a single person shown more than once. In the case above, the common ancestor may be shown as two offshoots of his parents, with each of those offshoots leading to exactly the same marriage among descendants - so you have parallel genealogies on the graph, with one showing the relationship to the husband and the other representing the relationship to the wife. In a genealogy with multiple intra-familial marriages, the number of parallel genealogies rapidly expands.

Comment: Please provide a link to the "similar question from 2012."

Comment: I don't understand your need yet. Do you want to remove duplicate persons from a visualization (for example, a family tree), or from the database of persons itself? I'm using Gramps, and it relates to persons by ID, so ancestors are stored once, even if they appear multiple times when looking from the descendants.

Comment: I too do not understand your issue. I use Family Historian and that only stores an individual once in its database regardless of how that individual is linked to other individuals in its records. In a chart it shows the multiple links with different coloured curved lines.

Comment: Given that there are 2 or more routes back from the base person to one of these ancestors, what requirements do you have for crossing or not crossing of the lines of descent? Bearing in mind that I at least am assuming that the resultant depiction has to be 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about a chart / diagram / tree display it is still not very clear from your second post. If that is the case the image below shows how Family Historian handles this eventuality with the different colour curved lines.

[image: Family Historian chart]